# Complex conics as a Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Consider the complex curve defined by $\{(x,y) \in \hat{\mathbb{C}}^2 | ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + f = 0 \}$ for some complex numbers $a,b,c,d,e,f$ (here $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is the Riemann sphere).

**Is it correct to say that this curve, seen as a Riemann surface, is simply the Riemann sphere ?**

My reasoning is the following. For generic coefficients $a,b,c,d,e,f$, one can shift and rescale $y$ in such a way that the equation becomes $y^2 = P(x)$, where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $2 = 2g+2$, from which I deduce that the genus should be $g=0$. The curve being a closed subset of a compact space, it is compact. Hence the uniformization theorem says that it is the Riemann sphere.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Maybe I should make the question more concrete : how should I describe the curve $y^2 = x^2 -1$ ?